# Joining multiple dataframes with multiple common columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have multiple dataframes like this-

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[3,4,5],'c':[4,6,7]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'d':[66,24,55],'c':[4,6,7]})
df3=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'f':[31,74,95],'c':[4,6,7]})
```

I want this output-

```
    a   c
0   1   4
1   2   6
2   3   7
```

This is the common columns across the 3 datasets. I am looking for a solution which works for multiple columns without having to specify the common columns as I have seen on SO( since the actual data frames are huge).

Comment: Do you want common columns only  or common columns with all the same elements?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma with elements

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce), [intersection](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html), [filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) and [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) could help with your usecase:

```
dfs = (df,df2,df3)
cols = [ent.columns for ent in dfs]
cols

[Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object'),
 Index(['a', 'd', 'c'], dtype='object'),
 Index(['a', 'f', 'c'], dtype='object')]

#find the common columns to all : 
from functools import reduce
universal_cols = reduce(lambda x,y : x.intersection(y), cols).tolist()
universal_cols

['a', 'c']

#filter for only universal_cols for each df
updates = [ent.filter(universal_cols) for ent in dfs]
```

If the columns and contents of the columns are the same, then you can skip the list comprehension and just filter from only one dataframe:

```
#let's use the first dataframe
output = df.filter(universal_cols)
```

If the columns' contents are different, then concatenate and drop duplicates:

```
#concatenate and drop duplicates
res = pd.concat(updates).drop_duplicates()

res  #output has the same result

    a   c
0   1   4
1   2   6
2   3   7
```

Comment: I am getting final df as empy even though I am getting a list of universal cols

Comment: What do u get when u select on just one dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce), to apply function `r_common` cumulatively to the dataframes of `dfs`, from left to right, so as to reduce the list of `dfs` to a single dataframe `df_common`. The [`intersection`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) method is use to find out the common columns in two dataframes `d1` & `d2` inside `r_common` function.

```
def r_common(d1, d2):
    cols = d1.columns.intersection(d2.columns).tolist()
    m =  d1[cols].eq(d2[cols]).all()
    return d1[m[m].index]

df_common = reduce(r_common, dfs) # dfs = [df, df2, df3]
```

Result:

```
# print(df_common)
   a  c
0  1  4
1  2  6
2  3  7
```

Answer (score 0):

If need filter columns names with same content in each DataFrame is possible convert it to tuples and compare:

```
dfs = [df, df2, df3]  
df1 = pd.concat([x.apply(tuple) for x in dfs], axis=1)
cols = df1.index[df1.eq(df1.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).all(axis=1)]

df2 = df[cols]
print (df2) 
   a  c
0  1  4
1  2  6
2  3  7
```

If columns names should be different and is necessary compare only content:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[3,4,5],'c':[4,6,7]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'r':[1,2,3],'t':[66,24,55],'l':[4,6,7]})
df3=pd.DataFrame({'f':[1,2,3],'g':[31,74,95],'m':[4,6,7]})

dfs = [df, df2, df3]  
p = [x.apply(tuple).tolist() for x in dfs]
a = set(p[0]).intersection(*p)
print (a) 
{(4, 6, 7), (1, 2, 3)}
```

Comment: I am getting a key error saying none of the columns in the cols  are there

Comment: The second solution doesnt return a dataframe with the column names ..it prints only the elements

Comment: @ubuntu_noob - one thing, do you need compare columns names and content? Or only content and columns names are not important like in second solution?